# Chess position for a cake

Tags: problems, knights

As weird as this question may seem, I am looking for a famous chess position to put in a birthday cake. Ideally the position should involve at least one knight and about 6 pieces.

Any idea of a good position matching this constraints?

Comment: Famous chess position or famous tactic? In either case, you could consider the [game of the century position](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Game_of_the_Century_%28chess%29) after his queen sack and just before the windmill tactics that occur after the knight is moved. Move 18/19.

Comment: It should be a famous position. I considered this game, however it has way too much pieces. I need a position with about 6-8 pieces for this cake.

Comment: One more try: How about the final position [here](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1001165)? While there are several more pieces than 8, you can certainly remove several white/black pawns and still arrive at the same effective position.

Comment: If you have ChessBase you can use it for this. Search a database of the famous games with a filter for material.

Comment: Saavedra position? No knight but that might not be possible.

Comment: What kind of a position do you want? An elegant puzzle with knight?

Comment: Yes! And about 5-6 puedes

Comment: Problem is that 6 pieces including a knight doesn't leave a lot of options (1 knight + 2 kings leaves only 3 other pieces). However if you want the knight to be star of the show smothered mate is one possibility, look at the little diagram at the top of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smothered_mate and add a white king somewhere legal on the board

Answer (score 6):

How about Philidor's mate?

http://ashbyivanhoechessclub.org.uk/juniors/checkmates/philidors-mate/

```
[Title "Philidor's Mate"]
    [FEN "1r4k1/3Q2pp/8/6N1/6K1/8/8/8 w - - 0 1"]

    1. Qe6+ Kh8 2. Nf7+ Kg8 3. Nh6+ Kh8 4. Qg8+ Rxg8 5. Nf7#
```

A well known pattern that involves a (sham) Queen sacrifice, a double-check, and a smothered mate delivered by the lowly Knight.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this very famous puzzle suits your cake :) White mates with knight extremely elegantly.

This puzzle was also in [Chessbase Christmas puzzles](http://en.chessbase.com/post/fifteen-years-of-chessbase-christmas-puzzles) in 2001.

```
[Title "Genrikh Kasparian, Shakhmaty v SSSR 1935"]
[FEN "2B3K1/8/3N1p1p/6pk/5P1P/6P1/7r/5r2 w - - 0 1"]

1. Ne8 Kg6 ( 1... f5 2. Bxf5 ) ( 1... Rxf4 2. Ng7+ Kg6 3. Bf5+ Rxf5 4. h5+ Rxh5
5. g4 ) 2. h5+ Rxh5 3. f5+ Rxf5 4. g4 Rf4 5. Bf5+ Rxf5 6. Ng7 Rf1 7. gxh5#
```

Comment: Position after 6.Ng7 is super sweet :-)